# Call async method in Global.asax and in HttpHandler - works not the same way

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, task

I have class:

```
public class AsyncTaskRunner
{
    public static Task<string> TaskToComplete;

    public static void Do()
    {
        if (TaskToComplete == null)
        {
            TaskToComplete = GetDataAsync();
        }
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var res = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");
            return res.StatusCode + " - " + DateTime.UtcNow + " - " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        }
    }
}
```

If I call **AsyncTaskRunner.Do()** in **Global.asax** and will use **AsyncTaskRunner.TaskToComplete.Result** in controller it works ok, task is completed and its result is available. If I call **AsyncTaskRunner.Do()** from sync HttpHandler (for instance) instead of **Global.asax** task is forever in **WaitingForActivation**. How are async methods handled in **Global.asax**?
**UPDATE**: I call it like this `context.Response.Write(AsyncTaskRunner.TaskToComplete.IsCompleted ? AsyncTaskRunner.TaskToComplete.Result : AsyncTaskRunner.TaskToComplete.Status.ToString());` So I don't block execution.

Comment: Please see: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: I've read it, don't see anything about global.asax.

Comment: And I don't use Result tp block workflow. Only when task is completed.

Comment: @mtkachenko: You're using `Result` here: "use AsyncTaskRunner.TaskToComplete.Result". You should be using `await` instead of `Result`.

Comment: @StephenCleary I've added code example how I call the result. So I don't understand why: task will be completed if I call AsyncTaskRunner.Do() from Global.asax; but the same code doesn't work for call AsyncTaskRunner.Do() in httphandler for instance. Task forver in WaitingForActivation.

Comment: @mtkachenko: Are you sure it *never* completes?

Comment: @StephenCleary yes. With Global.asax it works very fast. It's my code in zip http://www.filedropper.com/code_1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to do some asynchronous lazy initialization. I recommend you use my [`AsyncLazy<T>` class](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/):

```
public class AsyncTaskRunner
{
  public static AsyncLazy<string> TaskToComplete { get; } =
      new AsyncLazy<string>(() => GetDataAsync());

  private static async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
string data = await AsyncTaskRunner.TaskToComplete;
```

`GetDataAsync` will not be called until `TaskToComplete` is awaited the first time.